"dar el matarile" y otras expresiones de jerga regional
A veces las pruebas escritas sobre varias expresiones regionales de jerga no son fáciles de encontrar cuando no se encuentran en diccionarios. Esta pregunta fue borrada pero la estoy resucitando dada la respuesta interesante que he podido encontrar. ¿Qué quiere decir esta expresión?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@jachguate There is now another question on this matarile word. So the question is  duplicate. Do you realize that I was unable to suggest the second one be closed as a duplicate because for that, the question has to have had an answer that was chosen by an OP. I think the duplicate function was misunderstood on this site.

LA MARCACIÓN DIAFÁSICA DE LOCUCIONES VERBALES
EUFEMÍSTICAS
Inmaculada Penadés Martínez
Universidad de Alcalá

El estudio se centra en las locuciones verbales referidas a la esfera
de la muerte un campo de interdicción lingüistica que no suele estar
adecuadamente tratado en los diccionarios en relación con la marca
eufemisticao ni en relación con otras marcas de uso.

[...] Nota 14:

14 La de jergal solo está asignada a las locuciones dar el matarile,
dar matarile y dar mulé; por su parte, únicamente sacar la piel a
tiras está marcada como regional, además de ser coloquial; también hay
una sola locución con la marca histórico, dar el paseo, de la que,
además, se añade una información complementaria: (hist) En la Guerra
Civil de 1936; hacer la raya en medio y llevarse Pateta son
coloquiales y humorísticas; pasar a mejor vida es literaria o
humorística; y morir hasta el apuntador y no salvarse ni el apuntador
están marcadas como coloquiales con la información adicional Gralm
referido humoríst a una obra de teatro o una novela. Cabe puntualizar
que las locuciones que tienen la marca jergal y la marcada como
regional muestran en los corpus una utilización general que excede el
uso limitado a una jerga o a una región. Lo prueban ejemplos como los
siguientes, obtenidos del CREA y mediante el buscador Google
limitándose a España y a páginas en español:
a) Ahí [Pertur] se opuso
a los métodos violentos y criticaba «… la dinámica infernal de las
conspiraciones» internas y le dieron el matarile. Ya se sabe, el que
se mueve no sale en la foto como le pasó a Yoyes.
b) Junto a su amigo
del alma Otis Toole dio matarile a diez víctimas probadas, aunque él,
más chulo que un ocho, se autoatribuyera la friolera de 500.
c) «Doña
Rosita», entre dos bocanadas de su puro toscano, gritó: ‒ Que le den
mulé y que se cave su fosa.
d) Que hartura, Señor, aguantar a felones,
y encima de todo tener que mantenerlos, estamos dormidos o
narcotizados, no puedo entender que aún no le hayamos sacado la piel a
tiras a más de uno de esos que dicen que nos representan. No habré
sido políticamente correcto, ni quiero serlo, pero, por lo menos, me
he desahogado.

Estudio sobre locuciones 
El glosario en el estudio dice que dar el matarile es matar a una persona.  Vale la pena leerlo por completo. Este estudio me parece muy importante y por eso resucité la pregunta.
NOTA 8:

En el anexo incluido al final de este trabajo figura una tabla en
la que se recogen las 131 locuciones. En la primera columna
empezando por la izquierda, aparece el lema bajo el que las locuciones
se registran en el DiLEA, con el número correspondiente a la acepción,
si es el caso, y su definición en el mismo diccionario. En la segunda
columna, está anotada la marca que el diccionario académico (DLE)
asigna a la locución. La tercera columna muestra la marcación del
diccionario de Seco, Andrés y Ramos (2017) (DFDEA). Por último, la
cuarta columna ofrece la marca del DiLEA, excepción hecha de la de
eufemístico porque no se ha utilizado en este diccionario y porque se
da por sentado que, en principio, todas las locuciones la presentan,
si bien habría que analizar en el futuro si locuciones como arrancar
la piel a tiras, comer los hígados, hacer picadillo o llevar al
matadero son, por el contrario, sustitutos disfemísticos por motivar o
reforzar las asociaciones de las locuciones del ámbito interdicto
analizado.

Un termino en la tabla:  morir hasta el apuntador.
Producirse muchas muertes
Etiqueta, columna 3: Gralm referido
humorist a una obra de teatro o una novela
